# How can I enable compression on my site?

Tags: javascript, html, css, gruntjs, compression

## I want

my page to load faster or at least to load at it **best**.

I've **concatenated** & **minified** all of my `JS`, `CSS`, and even `HTML`.
I've also optimized most of my images using `Photoshop` and `ImageOptim` on a Mac. Now, I want to enable/configure the compression on my site.

---

## I'm new

the world of compression : `gzip/deflate`, and I'm trying to learn them.

---

## I've tried

setting it up within Grunt.

I've installed `npm install grunt-contrib-compress --save-dev`

Then, I have it configure like this

```
compress: {

    main: {

        options: { mode: 'gzip' },

        expand: true,
        cwd: 'img/',
        src: ['**/*'],
        dest: 'dist/img'
    }
}
```

---

## Testing

When I run `grunt` I got everything in my `img/` folder compressed and store in my `dist/img/`as expected.

```
Created dist/img/overlays/01.png (214 bytes)
Created dist/img/overlays/02.png (212 bytes)
Created dist/img/overlays/03.png (209 bytes)
Created dist/img/overlays/04.png (211 bytes)
Created dist/img/overlays/05.png (212 bytes)
Created dist/img/overlays/06.png (211 bytes)
Created dist/img/overlays/07.png (217 bytes)
Created dist/img/overlays/08.png (159 bytes)
```

---

## Comparing

Then, I went to the folder `dist/img/` and check the file size different. They're not that big different. Example , `58 kb` vs. `59 kb`

---

## Question

Right now, I only compress my images.
Do I need to compress my minify assets like : JS, CSS, HTML ?
What is the most efficient way to enable compression on our site ?

Please feel free to suggested me anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also compress your minified JS/CSS by adding the `report` option:

```
cssmin: {
    dist: {
       options: {
         report: 'gzip'
     },
     files: [{...

uglify: {
    options: {
        mangle: true,
        report: 'gzip'
    },
```

Use [`grunt-uncss`](https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss) to remove unused CSS from your projects.

If you're using compass, try [Spriting](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/) your images instead of just compressing them.

Comment: Thank you very much for improving my grunt knowledge.

Comment: Can I do `options: { report: 'gzip' }` with my htmlmin grunt package ?

Comment: I don't think you need to if you are serving your content using gzip compression (http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/). Instead just change the configuration for the `grunt-contrib-compress` to run trough all your generated asset not just `img`. (expand: true,
    cwd: 'assets/',
    src: ['**/*'],
    dest: 'public/'

Comment: `expand true` : what is that do ? , Okay, I will try to do that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Google has a good guide to optimize content efficiency. You can take a look [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/optimize-encoding-and-transfer?hl=en). The general idea is

- Compress text assets if possible
- Image is already compressed usually. Gzip/deflate cannot compress it much further. [Image optimization](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/image-optimization?hl=en) is a better way to reduce the payload size.
- Use [HTTP caching](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching?hl=en) whenever possible.

Comment: Thank you so much for directing me to the right track. :)

Answer (score 1):

> Right now, I only compress my images.

Don't. All the image formats used on the WWW have native compression schemes. You don't gain anything by adding gzip on top.

> Do I need to compress my minify assets like : JS, CSS, HTML?

Yes. Text files benefit from gzip compression.